# JQuery error on window.load()

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery, but I'm using it in a .NET 2.0 project to time our users out of the system after 13 minutes of inactivity.  I've got a function that basically blacks out the screen and gives them a button ton continue working.  It's been working for awhile, but only works inside of "child" windows because of the way I implemented it.

We're not using Master Pages technically, but I am trying to embed the code in what is our equivalent of a master page, and I'm running into a javascript error.  The code in question is:

```
$(window).load() {
    window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME);
}
```

The error I'm getting is that a ";" is expected.  I've tried:

```
$(window).load() {
    window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME);
};
```

and also tried:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME);
});
```

all with the same result.  Thanks in advance for your time and any possible suggestions!

Here is the code for my pop_init function:

```
function pop_init() {
    // show modal div
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("body").append("<div id='popup_overlay'></div><div id='popup_window'></div>");
    //$("#popup_overlay").click(popup_remove);  // removed to make sure user clicks button to continue session.
    $("#popup_overlay").addClass("popup_overlayBG");
    $("#popup_overlay").fadeIn("slow");

    // build warning box
    $("#popup_window").append("<h1>Warning</h1>");
    $("#popup_window").append("<p id='popup_message'>Your session is about to expire.  Please click the button below to continue working without losing your session.</p>");
    $("#popup_window").append("<div class='buttons'><center><button id='continue' class='positive' type='submit'><img src='images/green-checkmark.png' alt=''/> Continue Working</button></center></div>");

    // attach action to button
    $("#continue").click(session_refresh);

    // display warning window
    popup_position(400, 300);
    $("#popup_window").css({ display: "block" }); //for safari using css instead of show
    $("#continue").focus();
    $("#continue").blur();

    // set pop-up timeout
    SESSION_ALIVE = false;
    window.setTimeout("popup_expired()", 1000);
}
```

Well, I've made sure that all dependent functions are located above the code that calls them now, and I'm still getting the same error, so I'm at a loss.  The odd thing is that my overlay fades in, and then the error is thrown - but my popup with the continue button never shows.  So it's almost as if the error is between the overlay and the #popup_window construction.  I'm attaching my complete .js file.  There are some other functions in it that aren't concerned with this, but are for another part of the system, but I'm including them for completeness and the chance that perhaps there is interference of some sort:

// Following code is to handle session timeout
// Global variable used to set repeated session timeout calls.
//    Set SESSION_TIME to (# seconds) * 1000 for the total milliseconds
//    to wait before sending the popup windows to the user.
//    You should give the user two minutes before the session times out to respond,
//    e.g. for a 15 minute timeout, set it to 13 * 60 * 1000 = 780000 (~ 13 minutes).
var SESSION_TIME = 60000;

// Global variable used to test if the session has expired.  Set to true until popup
//    is shown to the user.  Reset when they click Continue.
var SESSION_ALIVE = true;

// determine size of popup window and adjust position
function popup_position(P_WIDTH, P_HEIGHT) {
    $("#popup_window").css({ marginLeft: '-' + parseInt((P_WIDTH / 2), 10) + 'px', width: P_WIDTH + 'px' });
}

// remove all added objects and restart timer
function popup_remove() {
    $("#popup_window").fadeOut("fast", function() { $('#popup_window,#popup_overlay').trigger("unload").unbind().remove(); });
    //if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight == "undefined") {//if IE 6
    $("body", "html").css({ height: "auto", width: "auto" });
    $("html").css("overflow", "");
    //}
    window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME);
}

// session ajax call from button click
function session_refresh() {
    SESSION_ALIVE = true;
    $(".buttons").hide();
    $("#popup_message").html("
Thank you!  You may now resume using the system.
");
    window.setTimeout("popup_remove()", 300);
    $("#popup_window").fadeOut("slow", function() { $('#popup_window,#popup_overlay').trigger("unload").unbind().remove(); });
    window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME);
}

// Main popup window handler
function pop_init() {
    // show modal div
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("body").append("");
    //$("#popup_overlay").click(popup_remove);  // removed to make sure user clicks button to continue session.
    $("#popup_overlay").addClass("popup_overlayBG");
    $("#popup_overlay").fadeIn("slow");

```
// build warning box
$("#popup_window").append("<h1>Warning</h1>");
$("#popup_window").append("<p id='popup_message'>Your session is about to expire.  Please click the button below to continue working without losing your session.</p>");
$("#popup_window").append("<div class='buttons'><center><button id='continue' class='positive' type='submit'><img src='images/green-checkmark.png' alt=''/> Continue Working</button></center></div>");

// attach action to button
$("#continue").click(session_refresh);

// display warning window
popup_position(400, 300);
$("#popup_window").css({ display: "block" }); //for safari using css instead of show
$("#continue").focus();
$("#continue").blur();

// set pop-up timeout
SESSION_ALIVE = false;
window.setTimeout("popup_expired()", 1000);
```

}

// First call to popup window
$(window).load(function() {
    window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME);
});

function popup_expired() {
    if (!SESSION_ALIVE)
    //window.location.href = "login.asp";
    //window.location.href = "default.aspx";
        window.close;
}

function replaceBadCharacters() {
    // Get all textboxes and text area controls
    $('input[type=text], textarea').each(function() {
        var txtobj = $('#' + this.id);
        txtobj.attr("value", txtobj.attr("value").replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8216), "g"), String.fromCharCode(39))); // Microsoft Word left-side apostrophe
        txtobj.attr("value", txtobj.attr("value").replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8217), "g"), String.fromCharCode(39))); // Microsoft Word right-side apostrophe
        txtobj.attr("value", txtobj.attr("value").replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8220), "g"), "'")); // Microsoft Word left-side quotes
        txtobj.attr("value", txtobj.attr("value").replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8221), "g"), "'")); // Microsoft Word right-side quotes
    });
}
// End of timeout code
//-------------------------------------------

// Following code is to warn users on Case Entry/Edit page that case will be saved if they click certain links
// (like to add Notes, change Collection Tables, etc.)
var calling_obj;

```
// call from cancel button click
function save_abort() {
    popup_remove();
} 

// call from continue button click
function save_continue() {
    //alert(calling_obj.id);     
    __doPostBack(calling_obj.id, '');
    popup_remove();
}

function warn_save(obj) {
// show modal div
//alert(obj.id);
$("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("body").append("<div id='popup_overlay'></div><div id='popup_window'></div>");
$("#popup_overlay").addClass("popup_overlayBG");
$("#popup_overlay").fadeIn("slow");

// build warning box
$("#popup_window").append("<h1>Save Case?</h1>");
$("#popup_window").append("<p id='popup_message'><center>Navigating away from the current page will automatically save this Case.  Do you want to continue?</center></p>");
$("#popup_window").append("<div class='buttons'><center><button id='continue' class='positive' type='submit'><img src='images/green-checkmark.png' alt=''/>Yes</button>&nbsp;<button id='cancel' class='positive' type='submit' alt=''><img src='images/delete.png' alt=''/>No</button></center></div>");

// attach action to button
$("#continue").click(save_continue);
calling_obj = obj;
$("#cancel").click(save_abort);

// display warning window
popup_position(400,300);
$("#popup_window").css({display: "block"}); //for safari using css instead of show
$("#continue").focus();
$("#continue").blur();
}

 // Case Entry div expand/close functions
function close_div_acct() {
    $("#div_acct").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting setTimeout in window.load is redundant, as window.setTimeout will be run on window.load.  You shouldn't need anything more than this:

```
window.setTimeout("pop_init()",SESSION_TIME);  //Added quotes so function isn't immediately run
```

Make sure SESSION_TIME and pop_init() are declared in the proper order.  If you're having any issues, it is most likely in your SESSION_TIME or pop_init() functions.

EDIT:  Make sure your session_time is in the correct order of magnitude, SESSION_TIME = 3000 is a timeout of 3 seconds.

Comment: SESSION_TIME is my first var declared, then a second var is declared, followed by my window.load function, followed by pop_init().  Is that not the correct order?  I'm aware of the millisecond timing, and even with SESSION_TIME set to 60000, I get the overlay showing immediately.

Comment: @Mike:

pop_init() should be declared before the window.load.  Also, are you just declaring SESSION_TIME or are you assigning it?  It sounds like you are assigning it later as your pop_init() is running but the timing isn't working.  Have you tried hardcoding a value into setTimeout and seeing if that works?

Comment: @Bryan, thanks!  I totally didn't think about location in the file - talk about a novice error!  DOH!  So I guess that, likewise, the popup_position function, being called from pop_init, needs to be declared *before* pop_init, and so on?

Comment: @Bryan, my first non-quote line in the file declares and sets SESSION_TIMEOUT:  var SESSION_TIME = 60000;  I tried hard-coding the value in the call to pop_init, but if I remove the quotes around "pop_init" in the window.load event, it fires the jquery overlay instantly, regardless of what is put for the time.

Comment: @Mike:

Yes, sry.  Javascript will execute the first argument immediately as a function.  If you put quotes around it, that should solve your problem.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well, I've totally de-constructed my page until I got no error, then re-constructed it and the offending code seems to be this line:

AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(GetType(RC_Navigation))

RC_Navigation is our equivalent of a master page.  The declaration doesn't include our Namespace, but I inserted that in a test to no avail.  One thing I'm wondering is whether RegisterTypeForAjax is an Ajax 2.0-only method.  We're not using Ajax 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried..

```
$(window).load(function() {
   setTimeout( pop_init, SESSION_TIME );
});
```

This doesn't invoke it automatically. Syntactically it's correct though. If that doesn't do it, the problem may lie elsewhere, possibly above this snippet of code.

Comment: You need quotes around "pop_init()" or it will execute automatically.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. Quotes in circumstances like this is a bad practice and using them would make it much slower. In addition, passing a reference does *not* invoke it immediately and usually is the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: Whenever I tried it without quotes, it *did* execute immediately, regardless of what I set for SESSION_TIME.

Comment: Nah, a reference is not invoked immediately. You and bryan.taylor were probably mistaken.

Comment: True, normally you are correct, but in whatever his instance was, it was executing it as a function.  I initially rec'd removing the quotes, but he said it was executing automatically and after adding them back in it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after completely de-constructing my page until I had no errors, and then re-constructing it until I came upon the error, it turned out that we were calling the Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax method, which apparently requires AjaxPro.2 and we were using the older version of AjaxPro.  I upgraded to AjaxPro.2 and got around the error.

Now I've got a new issue, though.  My timeout code (pop_init) is being called every SESSION_TIME seconds/minutes, regardless of the child window being used.  My timeout code is being called from what is our version of a master page (but is not technically a master page) and the parent window doesn't seem to recognize that the child window is still in use.  Any ideas for this one?

Thanks for all the great, detailed help from Bryan, meder and Nick!

Comment: No problem,  but you should accept/upvote all of our answers if you appreciated our help.  For your new problem, my suggestion is to post another question and link to it from here.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  window.setTimeout(pop_init, SESSION_TIME);
});
```

Though your last attempt should work or throw a different error.  It looks like the last statement *before* this one (possibly in an included file) isn't property terminated with a `;`.  Look through your code and look at the last JavaScript that runs before this, including files included via a `<script>` tag.  To test the theory, do this:

```
;$(window).load(function() {
  window.setTimeout(pop_init, SESSION_TIME);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to add the ')' before the closing ';'?  I don't see where the opening ( is for it

Comment: @Barlow - Thanks, complete brain lapse there, was more focused on the fact his last attempt *should* work (or throw a `pop_init` is not a function error).

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I tried all suggestions, and made some progress, as I am now throwing a different error at least. When I use this: $(window).load(function() { window.setTimeout("pop_init()", SESSION_TIME); }); I'm getting the following error: Object doesn't support this property or method, and the exact line is: if((t=n.leftMatch[H].exec(g))!=null&&t[2]) A few observations - I tried your suggestion, meder, and removed "window." from the call to setTimeout, and got the same error I'm getting now. Also, if I take the quotes off the call to pop_init nothing changes.

Comment: Actually, when I removed the quotes from the call to pop_init, I got the same error, but my window blacked out immediately, rathern than waiting for 1 minute (which is what I'm testing with as my timeout value).  Nick, adding the semi-colon at the beginning made no difference either.

Comment: @Mike - You're getting an error somewhere else, inside `pop_init()` it sounds like, you'll have to post that code as well.

Comment: @Nick - edited original post to include pop_init function.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike - None of the code you posted is directly related to the errors you've added in comments...if you had an example page maybe we can take a look, but there's something else going on outside the scope of your question.

Comment: @Nick - my jquery stuff happens as close to the top of the file as it can, right after the <head> tag.  The only thing above it is ASP.NET register, reference and page attributes/declarations.  Here's my references to the jquery files:

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="jscripts/RC_jquery.js" language="javascript"></script>